# How to solve Randomize in place algorithm in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I'm reading Introduction to Algorithms - Third edition and now, I have to implement RANDOMIZE-IN-PLACE algorithm which must permute each value from the current array.
The pseudocode provided by the book looks like this:

```
n = A.length
for i = 1 to n
swap A[i] with A[Random(i, n)]
```

I tried to implement that on C#, but I'm receiving an `IndexOutOfRangeException` sometimes (only in some cases). I used to debug the algorithm and found that when

```
randomValue = array[randomNumber.Next(index, upperBound)];
```

index is equal to `array.Length - 1` and upperBound is `array.Length - 1` (in other words the index and upperBound are the same values and the .Next looks like this `.Next(9, 9)` for example), the random generator is able to produce number 10 (lower bound / upper bound + 1) which is exactly my array.Length. If someone has any idea how to fix that will be very helpful for me. Thank again. Here is my C# code.

```
namespace RandomizedAlgorithms
{

using System;

class RandomizeInPlace
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        Randomize(array);

        for (int index = 0; index <= array.Length - 1 ; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[index]);
        }
    }

    private static void Randomize(int[] array)
    {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        int swapVariable = 0;
        int randomValue = 0;
        int upperBound = array.Length - 1;

        for (int index = 0; index <= array.Length - 1 ; index++)
        {
            randomValue = array[randomNumber.Next(index, upperBound)];
            swapVariable = array[randomValue];
            array[randomValue] = array[index];
            array[index] = swapVariable;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @MitchWheat it is Fisher-Yates, if I'm not mistaking

Comment: You don't need to swap the last value with itself.

Comment: But acording to the pseudocode, you want the .Next to be like (currentPosition, TotalAmountOfItems) :/

Comment: @NahuelIanni note that `upperBound = array.Length - 1`, which is essentially `TotalAmountOfItems`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `Random.Next(9,9)` produces 10? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) says it's impossible: `If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned.`

Comment: @J0HN, you can check that link, I'm providing a screenshot: [Click](https://www.dropbox.com/s/19yyfz8neo0gm47/Screenshot%202014-08-18%2013.53.09.png)

Comment: @StanimirYakimov: As dbc says in their answer the problem is that randomValue is not the result of your `Random.Next` call as it should be but a randomly selected value from your array which of course can be 10.

Comment: Please note `Random.Next(int)` 's upper bound is exclusive. `'The exclusive upper bound of the random number to be generated.'` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This means you should use `int upperBound = array.Length;`

Comment: @J0HN That is not correct, array.Length = 10 - 1 = maximum position inside the array that can be used without an exception, that is because the first index is 0 instead of 1.
.Length = total amount of items, .Length - 1 = index of the last item in the array.

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the random *index* of the element you are going to swap, rather than the array value itself:

```
private static void Randomize(int[] array)
{
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    int swapVariable = 0;
    int randomIndex;                // <-- renamed this
    int upperBound = array.Length;  // <-- See the comments

    for(int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
    {
        // Note: besides the minor changes above, the real fix is removing array[...]
        randomIndex = randomNumber.Next(index + 1, upperBound);
        swapVariable = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = array[index];
        array[index] = swapVariable;
    }
}
```

I've changed your code as little as possible, other improvements are possible. Note that this version allows an element to be "swapped" with itself, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: As stefan has reminded us in comments the upperBound also needs to be updated to be array.Length or the last item will never be shuffled (since it will never come up on the random number generator). Also your randomIndex should have a var before it for correctness.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I have updated the code. Does it look better now?

There are still several other improvements I would personally make, but I wanted to stay close to the OP's code.

Comment: Looks spot on now (I'd already plus oned you though so afraid you don't get any more from me ;-) ).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the array values as indices, via the variable `randomValue`:

```
        randomValue = array[randomNumber.Next(index, upperBound)];
        swapVariable = array[randomValue];
```

Your array values go from 1 to 10:

```
    int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

But arrays in c# are 0-based.  Change the array values to go from 0 to 9:

```
    int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

**Update**

OK, as commenters have pointed out, you're using the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm).  Here's a direct translation of that algorithm.  Note the weird asymmetry in the arguments to [`Random.Next(int minValue, int maxValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns `(minValue <= value < maxValue)`

```
public interface IRandomizer
{
    void RandomizeInPlace<T>(T[] array);
}

public class FisherYatesShuffle : IRandomizer 
{
    readonly Random randomNumber = new Random();

    public void RandomizeInPlace<T>(T[] array)
    {
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm , second version.
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
            var j = randomNumber.Next(i, array.Length); // i = inclusive lower bound; array.Length = The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned
            array.Swap(i, j);
        }
    }
}

public static class ListHelper
{
    public static void Swap<T>(this T[] list, int i, int j)
    {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (i != j)
        {
            T temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @J0HN - `randomValue` is being used as an array index.  It came as a value from the array.

Comment: Huh? Why would the randomization algorithm depend on the _values_ of the array you are shuffeling?

Comment: @CompuChip - I don't know, I'm not familiar with the algorithm.  I'm only pointing out a line of code that could cause the `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Right, I should have read more thoroughly. However, I didn't downvote.

Comment: Ah. I get what you were getting at now. I guess the what you really want to do is not change your array values though, but store the index in a temporary variable as well. It would not really make sense to write a function which can only shuffle the array { 0, ..., 9 }, would it?

Comment: @CompuChip - it does seem like an extremely limited thing to do, doesn't it?

Comment: @dbc: I think the correct fix should be `randomValue = randomNumber.Next(index, upperBound);` so that it stores a randomly selected index and not a randomly selected value. Your fix is, as CompuChip says a little crazy.